# Translation of "It is important to do it" in Spanish

Tags: traducción, subjuntivo

Could someone tell me the correct translation of the following sentence structure in Spanish,

> It is important to do it

or

> It is necessary to do it

and can I use all three of the following

> Es importante hacerlo
>
> Es importante para hacerlo
>
> Es importante que lo haga(s)..(Subjunctive mode)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is impersonal (It's important to do it) and the third one you are telling someone to do something (It's important that **you** do it)

Comment: The second could maybe make sense if there actually in omited subject.  ¿Para qué necesito el X cuando hago el Y?  Pues, es importante (el X) para hacerlo (el Y).  Okay, it's a stretch, but I like edge cases :)

Comment: @guifa Yes, it could make sense, but it means quite a lot of context. It would mean *It is important in order to do it*.

Comment: it makes sense to me.  I read it and thought to myself.. `It is vital in order to do it.`

Comment: The third one should be passive since you have no definite subject that it going to do `it`... `Es importante que se lo haga` ... it is important this it is done.